# Fixing a leak in water heater pipe joint

Tags: water-heater, leak

I had a new water heater put in and discovered a slow drip at the joint where the hot water pipe from the heater connects to the house piping. The installer claimed that he didn't touch that solder joint, the leak must have existed before and so it's not his problem! Anyway, I am a pretty handy person, have a propane torch, plumbing solder and flux. I would like to fix this myself before accepting defeat and call a real plumber!

To get a good joint and not have any water squirting out while I am working on this, I need to make sure there is no water in the pipes. Here is my plan of attack and wondering if this is safe and sound.

1. Turn off gas supply
2. Turn off cold water supply
3. Run hot water in a faucet or tub
4. Fix the solder joint
5. Open cold water supply
6. Turn the gas back on
7. Light the pilot

Would this be a good way to do it? Any words of wisdom will be gratefully received.

Thanks,

Comment: #2.5  Drain several gallons of water from water heater.

Comment: 4.1 - 4.5 Fixing the solder joint, in my humble opinion and experience, usually takes more that just heating the old joint up and sticking more solder on it, especially if it's been leaking and oxidizing for awhile. You might have to take the joint apart, clean off the old solder and redo it as new... or cut out the leak and reassemble with Shark bite connectors.

Comment: I find if there is water in the joint you will never seal it. As jack said you probably will need to take it apart and clean it. A trick I learned many years back to get the pipes dry and stay dry while soldering take some white bread no crust and make a plug on either side of the leaky Union. Reassemble and sweat it. I use mapp gas it works a bit better than propane with non lead solder. After it has cooled let the water flow the bread turns to mush and can be flushed out. If flushing to a faucet with an aerator remove it until the bread flows down the drain. 1 drop of water can cause a leak.

Comment: @AlaskaMan - thanks. I will be doing this.

Comment: @JACK and "Ed Beal" - thanks for your advice. My plan is to clamp a locking pliers, heat the joint, knock it loose, clean, flux and solder it again. TBH, I have never done this and did some research. Hopefully, it goes well and SWMBO will be appeased.